# Self hosted supabase concurrent data entry

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am using a self-hosted supabase and trying to make 1000 entries to the DB concurrently every second, but the supabase starts returning forbidden after 500 entries.

Tried increasing the max_connection of postgress but that didn't solve the problem. and I don't think it's a connection problem. Can anyone explain the cause and how to fix this?